# Conteúdo do site móvel com click jQuery

Tags: jquery, html5, addclass

Gostaria de aplicar a seguinte função em um projeto.

Quando clicado no botão (que aplicado, será o botão do menu) o conteúdo inteiro do site que está dentro da div `CONTEUDO-MOVEL` deve ir para esquerda escondendo uma parte do conteúdo, pois a section que ele se encontra está com `OVERFLOW:HIDDEN` e o conteúdo da `div class="MENU"` iria ficar visível.

Esta é a primeira ação.

Após isso, se o usuário clicar fora da `DIV CLASS="MENU"`, a classe `MOVE-LEFT` é removida e o site volta a seu estado inicial, escondendo o menu lateral.

Segue estrutura e link do jsfiddle:

HTML:

```html
<section id="conteudo"><a href="#" class="move">MENU</a>
    <div id="conteudo-movel">

        <div class="cont"></div>
        <div class="menu"></div>

    </div>

</section>
```

CSS:

```css
#conteudo
{position:absolute;relative;width:500px;height:200px;background:#f6f6f6;overflow:hidden;}
#conteudo-movel
{position:absolute;width:700px;height:100px;background:#000;left:0;}
.cont{width:500px;background:#c1c1c1;height:50px;position:relative;float:left;}
.menu{width:200px;background:#c1c1c1;height:50px;position:relative;float:left;}
.move{left:0;}
.move-left{left:-200px!important;}
```

Javascript:

```js
$( "a.move" ).click(function() {
   $( "#conteudo-movel" ).addClass( "move-left" );
      $( "this" ).removeClass( "move-left" );
});
```

[Modelo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9gn67k3/2/).

Comment: como @EduardoSilva respondeu, isto pode ser feito com off-canvas. porém se você tiver interrese numa implementação já pronta, pode olhar o seguinte link: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/offcanvas.html

Answer (score 2):

Você pode reproduzir esse efeito utilizando apenas CSS, isso se chama `off-canvas`.

Primeiro vamos arrumar o seu HTML:

```
<ul class="conteudo">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Página 1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Página 2</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Página 3</a></li>
</ul>

<input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />
<label for="nav-trigger">Menu</label>

<div class="conteudo-movel">
    <p>Meu menu off-canvas.</p>
</div>
```

- `conteudo` colocamos primeiro pois está "atrás" de `conteudo-movel` e
  qualquer outro conteúdo do site, você pode usar uma `div` ou
  `section` no lugar da `ul` se preferir.

Agora o nosso CSS:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.conteudo {
    background: #f6f6f6;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-trigger {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

label[for="nav-trigger"] {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    left: 15px;
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #f00;
}

.nav-trigger:checked + label {
    left: 515px;
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .conteudo-movel {
    left: 500px;
}

.nav-trigger + label, .conteudo-movel {
    transition: left 0.2s;
}

.conteudo-movel {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 4em;
    background-color: #000;
    background-size: 200%;
}
```

Note que utilizamos o seletor `~` pra atingir o `conteudo-movel` quando o checkbox é selecionado. Por fim, colocamos o atributo `overflow-x: hidden` pra nossa tag `body` para prevenir que os usuários possam dar scroll horizontal.

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9gn67k3/5/).

Comment: Genial, é exatamente isso. Interessante pois não conhecia a função ~ no css.. como pesquiso isso para estudar mais ? Mais uma coisa, no esse efeito de css é aceito por todos navegadores e tal?

Comment: Pesquise por `css selectors` ou `seletores css` no Google, existem diversos sites com materiais excelentes pra estudos. Sobre a compatibilidade vou ficar lhe devendo essa resposta, nunca cheguei a utilizar muito o `off-canvas`, mas acho que se você for seguindo as práticas css `cross-browser` não deverá apresentar problema.

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza o .animate() do jQuery para movimentar suas divs.

Exemplo movendo a primeira div para baixo:

```
$( "a.move" ).click(function() {
    $(".cont").animate({"bottom":"-=50px"},"slow");
});
```

Você pode movimentar sua div em todas as direções (top, right, bottom, left)

Mais exemplos em: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, melhorei a resposta.

Comment: @LeoCBS, aqui funcionou, agora como eu faço para remover a ação quando o usuario clicar em qualquer elemento que não esteja dentro da ´div class="menu"´ ?

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas acredito que pode capturar o click do `document` e verificar o target do seu evento, algo como: `$(document).click(function(e){/*corrigir a condição do if*/ if(e.target == "conteudo-movel") /*oculte a div aqui*/});`